# Updating an assembly reference to target new version

Tags: assemblies, versioning

I have been doing this by a really long process that I found out and I am sure there is a better way of doing it. I am finally fed up with my process and I am going to try to find out how to do it properly.

I have a solution which references and out of date assembly. For example, Castle.Core 1.0.3. I have newer version of Castle.Core, version 1.0.3.5422. I delete the old reference, replace assembly with new one, then add the reference to Castle.Core, but this time it is (supposed to be) a newer version. The solution still says I am referencing the old one when I deleted it and everything. I thought initially that the old assembly was hiding in the obj or bin folder so I deleted everything in the folder. Still happens. After a while of fiddling with it, I finally get it.

This is incredibly annoying, especially when I trying to update like 5 assemblies at once.

Help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I set Specific Version to true, it won't make any difference as the reference allready is set to an older version. My problem is specifically adding a reference with the file explorer, finding the assembly, seeing that the version is 1.0.3.5442 and the when it gets added to VS, it is an older version

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Specific Version set to true?

If not, it will use the version you point to, even though VS will still report the old version (greyed out)

Comment: If I set Specific Version to true, it won't make any difference as the reference allready is set to an older version. My problem is specifically adding a reference with the file explorer, finding the assembly, seeing that the version is 1.0.3.5442 and the when it gets added to VS, it is an older version